# How to provide data concurrency using oracle database?

Tags: database, oracle

I have a situation where I have a oracle database table which is available to end users for reporting purposes (only select queries). This is a fully replaced table and everyday when the data arrives I have to truncate the entire table and load it again with the new data. While I do this I want my table to be always available for the reporting. But I dont want to make a copy of this table to achieve this.

Comment: You may be able to do that with oracle flashback.  .

Comment: Instead of truncating can you use `DELETE` and `INSERT`?  It would be slower, but it wouldn't block any readers.

Comment: Actually there is another problem, there are almost 30 such tables that are part of the data model, what I want to achieve is that I do either all the tables get loaded or none, so for example if the insert fails for one table, all 30 tables should go back to the previous state. Would really appreciate if anyone could help.

Answer (score 0):

You can `DELETE` and `INSERT` as much as you want within a single transaction, and no readers will know the difference until the final `COMMIT`.  You can use a PL/SQL block like this to group the statements, and roll back the changes if there are any errors.

```
begin
    delete from mytable1;
    insert into mytable1 select ...;

    delete from mytable2;
    insert into mytable2 select ...;

    ...


    commit;

exception when others then
    rollback;
    raise;
end;
/
```